# How to make field depends on lst_price of product.product but can be editable

Tags: model, field, product, odoo-10

I want to make the field in the same model `product.product`

let's say A which is depends on `lst_price of product.product`.

if user not set value of A then its take lst_price but if User will set the value of A then its set as it is.
Also A field value change on variant price set.

> amount=fields.Float(compute="_compute_amount",inverse="_set_amount",store=True)

```
@api.depends('lst_price')
def _compute_amount(self):            
    for product in self:
        if product.amount<product.lst_price:
            product.amount = product.lst_price

@api.one            
def _set_amount(self):
    return True
```

Comment: You can use an inverse function in that field.

Answer (score 1):

let say you want to create field in product.product which will populate on the lst_price change also can be change by user.

You can achieve it like this.

```py
A = fields.AnyType(compute="get_value_on_lst_price", inverse="set_value_by_user",store=True)

@api.depends('lst_price')
def get_value_on_lst_price(self):
    for product in self:
        product.A = Any_Calculation_Using_lst_price

@api.one
def set_value_by_user(self):
    return True
```

Comment: Using this code when i set variant price i cant see the changes in depends field A.